# USB flash drive is write protected

Tags: usb

I have this flash drive that I grabbed from work that has a few files on it I would like to delete.

It is a 32GB flash drive and when trying to delete the data I get this error message:

> "This Drive is write protected."

Is there a way to change this on a Mac? I have tried erasing the drive and get this error.

[image]

Here is all the information about this Drive. Any ideas? 
[image]

I have tried changing this on a Windows as well by going into regedit and changing the WriteDefault to 0, I had to actually create that 32-WRD key because there was none initially. I restarted the computer and no luck. I also tried going into Command Prompt and clearing the partitions on it with no luck either.

Comment: A knuckle-head suggestion but did you toggle the physical button on the USB. Write-protection can sometimes be turned off this way.

Answer (score 1):

It's NTFS so OSX by default can't write to the device - even to erase it. You'll need to format it into another file system (e.g., FAT32, exFAT, OSX Journaled, or find a beta of [Mac's new APFS file system](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

You can also try to install an NTFS tool for OSX like [NTFS For Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/).